# Filter a data frame if columns names have not a specific string

Tags: python, pandas

If this

```
data_no_control.loc[:, data_no_control.columns.str.contains('NGS')]
```

takes values which columns have an 'NGS' in their names.

How can I take the values of columns which names have not 'NGS' in the name

Comment: this question had been closed for the wrong reason, and the related link has nothing to do with it, otherwise here's how you can filter out columns not containing a specific word  : "data.filter(regex="^((?!NGS).)*$",axis=1)" .